# Phonegap and In App Purchase for ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using Phonegap Build and I just cannot get it to connect for testing.

The plugin I'm using is: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase

I have added this to the config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cc.fovea.plugins.inapppurchase" version="3.4.0" />
```

Then I have added a js file and added this code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeStore, false);
function initializeStore() {

store.verbosity = store.INFO;

store.register({
id: "com.myapp.app.product1",
alias: "2 Messages",
type: store.CONSUMABLE
});

store.ready(function() {
console.log("\\o/ STORE READY \\o/");
alert("Store is ready");
});

store.refresh();
}
```

My problem is that I'm not getting the alert saying:

Store is ready

I also created a Sandbox account and logged into my iphone using the sandbox login and still no alert.

Why is this not working?

I'm just using phonegap build and a pc as I don't have a mac.

Do I need xcode or a mac in order to test in-app-purchases with phonegap ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From now on you can use phonegap build with any cordova plugins. You should specify the source tag, for example:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

In the case of the in app purchase plugin, I haven't tested it, but it should be:

```
<gap:plugin name="cc.fovea.plugins.inapppurchase" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

**EDIT**
To stay updated with the plugin, remove version tag. Every time you compile the app again, the latest version will be used.